# A space homotopy dominated by a wedge of spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homotopy-groups-of-sphere

Recall that the space $A$ is homotopy dominated by $X$ if there are maps $f:A\longrightarrow X$ and $g:X\longrightarrow A$ such that $gf\simeq id_A$.

Suppose that $X$ is a wedge of some spheres and $A$ homotopy dominated by $X$. Let $K$ be a bouquet of circles so that map $\phi :K\longrightarrow A$ induces an isomorphism on fundamental groups. Put $\pi_2 (\phi )=\pi_2 (M,K\times 1)$ where $M$ is the mapping cylinder of $\phi$. I know that $\pi_2 (\phi )$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (A)$-module. My question is that: how do I prove $\pi_2 (\phi )$ is free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (A)$-module?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case when $A$ is itself equivalent to a wedge of spheres is easy. In the general case, $\pi_2(\phi)$ is a direct summand of $\pi_2(\phi')$, where $\phi'\colon K \to X$ is the map $f\phi$. The result follows because projective modules over the group ring of a free group are free modules, by a [theorem of Hyman Bass](http://ac.els-cdn.com/002186936490016X/1-s2.0-002186936490016X-main.pdf?_tid=8518c33a-988d-11e7-9fb3-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1505312104_4cb454828a91f3fbb299616a3338cb2c).

Comment: Excuse me. Could you explain more? Why $\pi_2 (\phi )$ is a direct summand of $\pi_2 (\phi ')$? Then if this is true, is $\pi_2 (\phi ')$ $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (A)$-module which be comparable with $\pi_2 (\phi )$ as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (A)$-module?

Comment: (1) Because $\phi$ is a retract of $\phi'$. (2) They are both ${\mathbb Z}[\pi_1(K)]$-modules, and $\pi_1(K)\cong \pi_1(A)$.

Comment: I understood that $\phi$ is a retract of $\phi '$. Also, I agree with the fact that $\pi_2 (\phi )$ is a $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (K)$-module.

Comment: But I don't understand how does $\pi_2 (\phi ')$ is a $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (K)$-module? Since maybe $\pi_1 (K)$ and $\pi_1 (X)$ are not isomorphic!

Comment: In general, $\pi_1(K)$ acts on the relative homotopy groups $\pi_1(M_f, K)$ for any map $f\colon K \to X$. See, for example, Hatcher's book page 345

Comment: That's true. I understood. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I understood that $\phi$ is a retract of $\phi '$ and so, $\pi_2 (\phi )$ is a direct summand of $\pi_2 (\phi ')$ as a $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (K)$-module. Hence if $\pi_2 (\phi ')$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (K)$-module, then $\pi_2 (\phi)$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (K)$ modue and so by Bass's Theorem is a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (K)$-module. But why $\pi_2 (\phi ')$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (K)$-module?

Comment: I just know that if $\phi'$ is a map from a bouquet of circles $K'$ to $X$ which induces isomorphism on fundamental groups, then $\pi_2 (\phi ')$ is a free  $\mathbb{Z}$-module by the paper  ''Finiteness conditions for CW-complexes'' from C.T.C. Wall.

Comment: Because $\pi_1(K)$ is a subgroup of $\pi_1(K')$.

Comment: Excuse me. But I don't understand how does this happen.

Comment: I'm sorry. But I really can't  why $\pi_2 (\phi ′)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(K)$-module!

Comment: $\pi_2(\phi')$ is a free $\mathbb Z[\pi_1(X)]$-module, and $\pi_1(K)$ injects into $\pi_1(X)$. Therefore, it is also a free $\mathbb Z[\pi_1(K)]$-module.

Comment: Could you give me a reference for this statement please?

Comment: If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $\mathbb Z[G]$ is a free module over $\mathbb Z[H]$. This follows from the fact that $G$ is isomorphic, as a set with an action of $H$, to a disjoint union of copies of $H$ (the cosets). It follows that every free $\mathbb Z[G]$-module is also free as a $\mathbb Z[H]$-module. I don't know a published reference. This stackexchange question is posed for finite groups, but the answer holds for arbitrary discrete groups. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059430/is-the-restriction-of-the-regular-representation-of-a-finite-group-always-a-mult

Comment: Your answer is so perfect.  I learned a lot of lessons of your valuable hints. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry. I worked on this problem but I can't understand it. You told me put $\phi '=f\phi :K \longrightarrow X$. Now let $L$ be a wedge of circles and $\psi :L\longrightarrow X$ be the inclusion so that $\psi$ induces an isomorphism on fundamental groups. Now we know $\pi_2 (\psi )$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1 (X)]$-module. Since $\pi_1 (K)$ injects into $\pi_1 (K)$, then $\pi_2 (\psi )$ is also a free $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1 (K)]$-module. But I don't understand what relation is there between $\pi_2 (\psi )$ and $\pi_2 (\phi ')$ as $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1 (K)]$-module?

Comment: My question is that why $\pi_2 (\phi )$ is a direct summand of $\pi_2 (\phi ')$ as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (K)$-module. You told me (second comment after the answer) that $\phi$ is a retract of $\phi'$. But $(M_{\phi},K)$ and $(M_{\phi'},K)$ are pairs  and so we need actually  relative   maps $\bar{f}:(M_{\phi},K)\longrightarrow (M_{\phi '},K)$ and $\bar{g}:(M_{\phi '},K)\longrightarrow (M_{\phi},K)$ so that $\bar{g}\circ \bar{f}\simeq 1_{(M_{\phi},K)}$. I couldn't find them.